# My SQL - How to run different WHERE statements on different weekdays, like one for monday and another for friday

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, getdate

I missunderstod this a lot and thanks again for all the help.
I eventually found a solution for my case and it didn't even involve anything like 
     *IF Monday THEN SELECT*
I didn't even needed a CASE-statement.

What I had to do was to put different WHERE statements with an OR in between.

I have stated my final code bolow:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT 
    t.pay_date
    , t.supp_name
    , t.client AS row_client
    , t.ip_status
    , t.bank_account
    , t.remitt_curr AS remitt_curr
    , t.remitt_id
    , t.apar_id  
    , t.payment_id
  FROM 
    aipheader t
  WHERE 
    DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) IN (2,3,4) 
    AND 
    t.pay_date   BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE())
  OR 
    DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) IN (5,6) 
    AND 
    t.pay_date   BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE())) x
ORDER BY 1
```

The statement above will execute the OR-block that is true, in my case the one with the rigt weekday.

********* OLD QUESTIONS BELOW ***********

I want to run different SELECT statements on different days off the week.

I can actually get the following code to work:

```
select 
   case 
      when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 4 then 
         (select 'HELLO' ) 
      ELSE 
         (select 'GOODBYE') 
   end
```

On a wendsday the code above returns "HELLO", every other workday it would returns "Goodbye". So far so good!

As long as the select statement only return one value it seams to work, but I realy want a full table like below.

The only differance here should be the [* FROM table] part, and it breaks it all:

```
select 
   case 
      when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 4 then 
         (select * FROM table1) 
      ELSE 
         (select * FROM table2) 
   end
```

If I can't even make the above to work I can not make different SELECTs for different workdays, so this is the hard ting to figure out.

I have tried to encapsulate things with () and add a few SELECTs in different ways but it do not work, so it is probably some SQL principal.

I get an error that I think says that this is ok if it is only one value that's returned:

> SqlState  37000 Native 116  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Only one expression can be specified in the select list when
>   the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

THANKS FOR ALL OF THE REPLYS I NOW UNDERSTAND IT A BIT BETTER.

I was not looking to add a column, I tought I could make a complete new SELECT statement. I now see that my CASE statement only adds a column, as you point out.

So then my first ide might be a better aproce, to actually modify the WHERE-clause in the select statement.

I have now tried that but it does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM aipheader t
   WHERE 
     CASE 
         WHEN DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())  = 4 THEN 
           t.pay_date = '2019-10-15'
         ELSE
           t.pay_date = '2019-10-17'
      END
```

It returns the error:

> SqlState  37000 Native 102  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near '='.

I have tried the simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM aipheader t
   WHERE 
     t.pay_date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-120,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY,-5,GETDATE())
```

The above is a simpler form, but that one returns the right values.
But the one obove that one with the CASE-clause return the error about "="-sign.

Maybee the CASE part in a WHERE statement do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit, the correct way to filter your date would be the following:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    aipheader t
WHERE
    t.pay_date = CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 4 THEN '2019-10-15' ELSE '2019-10-17' END
```

However, do you really want to hard-code the `2019-10-15` and `2019-10-17` dates? Seems like these should be computed automatically as time goes.

---

Be careful when using `DATEPART` with `DW`, since the week number starting point can actually change depending on the server's and/or current session settings. Check this example:

```
DECLARE @TestDate DATE = '2020-01-01' -- Wednesday

SET DATEFIRST 1 -- 1: Monday, 7: Sunday

SELECT DATEPART(DW, @TestDate) -- Returns 3

SET DATEFIRST 7 -- 1: Sunday, 7: Saturday

SELECT DATEPART(DW, @TestDate) -- Returns 4!
```

So whenever checking for a particular day of the week, make sure to force the `DATEFIRST` session parameter to a particular value so it's consistent with your checks.

Comment: Thank this is very good, now I will try to make it BETWEEN insted of "=" and  I think I got it. The first part was the "IF then" ide, and it did not turn out at all with the DECLERE statement, even tough that was what I was probably after, it did not return an error but nothing happend, I have I kind off simple form of SQL, it is not T-SQL.

Comment: I mark this as the solution when it was the answer that set me on the right track. I probably have to rewrite the question. I find the way eventueally and it didn't even inwolw any CASE it could be done with an OR. But big thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what you are trying to achieve. 
Of course your statement will not work, because your `select` statement in the `case when` returns multiple columns and rows. That cannot work, because your `case when` statement will display **one column**!

So what you can do is the following:

```
select 
   case 
      when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())  = 4 then 
         'HELLO'
      ELSE 
         'GOODBYE'
   end as [someField],
   *
from
   [table]
```

This query will have all rows and columns from `table` as output + the `someField` displaying `HELLO` or `GOODBYE`.
If you want to display different data from the table on the different dates (wednesday or not wednesday), you can alter the query this way:

```
select 
   case 
      when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())  = 4 then 
         [table].[field1]
      ELSE 
         [table].[field2]
   end as [someField],
   *
from
   [table]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this ur looking for ? Sub query should return 1 row and specify col name

```
select 
   case 
      when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 4 then 
         (select top 1 col1  from table1 ) 
      ELSE 
         (select top 1 col2  from table2 ) 
   end as result

 From table
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE WHEN` can only return a *single value* for each `THEN`, and *never* a Result Set with multiple rows and/or columns. That is just how `CASE WHEN` works.

You can achieve what you need like this:

```
DECLARE @DAY INT = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())

select * FROM table
WHERE (@DAY = 4 AND table.SomeCol = SomeValue)
OR    (@DAY = 5 AND table.SomeCol = SomeOtherValue)
... repeat for other days
```

Or like this:

```
DECLARE @DAY INT = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())

IF @DAY = 4
    (select * FROM table WHERE table.SomeCol = SomeValue)
ELSE IF @DAY = 5
    (select * FROM table WHERE table.SomeCol = SomeOtherValue)
... repeat for other days
```

Or like this:

```
DECLARE @DAY INT = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())

select * FROM table
WHERE @DAY = 4 AND table.SomeCol = SomeValue
UNION ALL
select * FROM table
WHERE @DAY = 5 AND table.SomeCol = SomeOtherValue
UNION ALL
... repeat for other days
```

My preference would probably be either the 1st or 2nd form.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot, I whent with the OR way to go, because it is actually different WHEREs I whant for different days of the week. I now can see how simple it can be that way, even tough an IT THEN solution would have been more general, this actually made it woork.

Answer (score 0):

A query must return before-known columns. If the tables `table1` and `table2` have different columns, you cannot write one query that returns, say, table1's five columns one day and table2's nine columns another.

As long as the resulting columns stay the same, however, you can join optionally. Here is a small example:

```
select
  p.project_id,
  p.project_name,
  coalesce(c1.name, c2.name) as team_member,
  coalesce(c1.salary, c2.salary * (1.0 + c2.tax / 100.0)) as team_member_salary,
  coalesce(c1.job_name, c2.job_title) as team_member_job
from project p
left join crew1 c1 on c1.project_id = p.project_id and datepart(dw, getdate()) = 4
left join crew2 c2 on c2.project_id = p.project_id and datepart(dw, getdate()) <> 4
order by p.project_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand what you are trying to achieve here. This example assumes that you are reading from different tables based on the date and will return all of the rows from both tables:

```
select * from (
    select 'HELLO' as col1, * from table1 where DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())  = 4
    UNION ALL
    select 'GOODBYE' as col1, * from table2 where DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())  <> 4
)
order by col1
```